# Saving a text typed by a user in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I just started programming and i don't have any experience. I'm trying to make a simple blog where you can type some text in a textarea but i don't know how to save it and display it on your webpage. When I search for an answer online, I only find information about how to convert it to another type of file. I just want to be able to type some text in a textarea and when you press enter display it on the webpage and eventually even make a new fresh textarea.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to save info entered by the user you can use `localStorage` or a database

Comment: StackOverflow isn't the place to ask these broad questions. Your going to need to have some kind of back-end and some way to save it. The most common would be some sort of database, either MySQL (or MariaDB) or Postgres or similar. Search around for "how to save a form to a database" or something to that effect.

Comment: Try to use localstorage or cookies, find out.

Answer (score 0):

A blog is probably one of a more complex task to do. I would recommend thinking of some simpler projects if you just started.

The reason why it's complicated is because you need to worry about a scheme to store your data and handle it. You could just save data to localstorage (a database built into your web browser) which would be the simplest. However you will not be able to read your blog on the internet or on another machine because your data is stored and can only be accessed by your browser on your computer. If you wanted a system where you can have access to your blog any where, you'd have to set up a server/database architecture which is probably a lot more complicated for a beginner. But if you are interested checking out node.js, express.js, mongoose, mongodb might get your started on something.

Also if you want this blog to be restricted by password or user auth that will also make your project 10 folds more complicated as you will have to learn about hashing, various security procedures, etc. This is why something like a blog is actually quite complicated to implement.